# res.cookie() not working in Nodejs/Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, cookies

Pls help me figure out where I am going wrong.

**Problem:** When I login and then refresh, I get logged out.

**Expected:** Upon logging in, a cookie should be set by Node, which should be sent to the server for every request. Which is not happening.

The app runs an initializer function to try and auto authenticate based on the token present in the cookie.

**Angular initializer function**

```
export function appInitializer(accountService: AccountService) {
  return () => new Promise(resolve => {
    // attempt to refresh token on app start up to auto authenticate
    accountService.refreshToken()
      .subscribe()
      .add(resolve);
  });
}
```

**Angular Account Service**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AccountService {
  private accountSubject: BehaviorSubject<Account>;
  public account: Observable<Account>;
  ....

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
    this.accountSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Account>(null);
    this.account = this.accountSubject.asObservable();
  }

  login(userName: string, password: string) {
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${this.reqUrl}/authenticate`, {userName, password})
      .pipe(map(account => {
        this.accountSubject.next(account);
        this.startRefreshTokenTimer();
        return account;
      }));
  }

  refreshToken() {
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${this.reqUrl}/refresh-token`, {})
      .pipe(map(account => {
        this.accountSubject.next(account);
        this.startRefreshTokenTimer();
        return account;
      }));
  }

  private refreshTokenTimeout;

  private startRefreshTokenTimer() {
    // parse json object from base64 encoded jwt token
    const jwtToken = JSON.parse(atob(this.accountValue.jwtToken.split('.')[1]));

    // set a timeout to refresh the token a minute before it expires
    const expires = new Date(jwtToken.exp * 1000);
    const timeout = expires.getTime() - Date.now() - (60 * 1000);
    this.refreshTokenTimeout = setTimeout(() => this.refreshToken().subscribe(), timeout)  
  }
```

**Node Route**

```
router.post('/authenticate', AccountController.authenticateSchema, AccountController.authenticate);
router.post('/refresh-token', AccountController.refreshToken);
```

**Node Acct Controller**

```
exports.authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
  const { userName, password } = req.body;
  const ipAddress = req.ip;
  accountService.authenticate({userName, password, ipAddress})
    .then(({refreshToken, ...account}) => {                        
      setTokenCookie(res, refreshToken);              // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
      res.json(account);
    })
    .catch(next);   
}

exports.refreshToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.refreshToken;
  if(!token) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'acct ctlr rTkn not found'});  // <<< even after Login and refresh I reach here 
  }
  const ipAddress = req.ip;
  accountService.refreshToken({token, ipAddress})
    .then(({refreshToken, ...account}) => {                 
      setTokenCookie(res, refreshToken);
      res.json(account);
    })
    .catch(next);    // ?
}

function setTokenCookie(res, token) {
  // create cookie with refresh token that expires in 1 day
  const cookieOptions = {
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1*24*60*60*1000)
  };
  res.cookie('refreshToken', token, cookieOptions);           ///?
}
```

I get this error in dev tool upon starting the appand also when i refresh after logging in.
[image]

Comment: You can try to add {withCredentials: true} to your http client requests..

Comment: I had that earlier. However, when I add ```{withCredentials: true}```, I get cors related error that I can not use '*' in   ```res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')```  Actually I dont need CORS policy in prod environment, bcos I will put the Angular app within Node app, so I will be removing that. However, while developing I am using separate Node and Angular apps. Any workaround for that?

Comment: Adding that option and fixing your cors error seems to be the only way to fix this. Unless you can run everything on the same domain/port

Comment: Ah.. I see your edit. Yes you can probably solve this dev time using an angular proxy: https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/

Comment: cool. It worked. But instead of proxy, I edited the cors header.
```res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);```

Comment: Cool, well done

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
```